# Azure application gateway redirect browser

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-application-gateway

We have recent shifted from nginx ingress to azure application gateway.

When using nginx we had a redirect in place as per the following;

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    rewrite ^/$ https://company.com.au/tech permanent;
    rewrite ^/portal(.*)$ /fpp$1 permanent;
```

This would redirect users in the browser to the correct page

Now that we are using application gateway I'm trying to replicate this behaviour but constantly getting 502 bad gateway and no redirect in the browser.

1. I tried this re-write rule - but that didn't seem to work

```
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-rule-set: |
      [
        {
          "rule-name": "portal-to-fpp",
          "rule-sequence": 1,
          "match-variables": [
            {
              "variable-name": "RequestUri",
              "selector": "$requestUri",
              "operator": "Contains",
              "variable-type": "Pattern"
            }
          ],
          "transforms": [
            {
              "transform-name": "rewrite",
              "pattern": "^/portal(.*)$",
              "replacement": "/fpp$1",
              "transform-type": "Rewrite"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

2. I tried adding a rule that was a backend target redirection on the HTTPS listner, however the browser does not redirect

any thoughts please?